# Unable to Remove Carriage Returns and Line Feeds Without Using Debug.Write()

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am trying to output serial data from a GUI in Visual C# onto a text file, however, when I output it, it prints one character on each line.  I have tried to replace the carriage returns and line feeds using .TrimEnd('\r','\n'), .Trim(), and .Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").

The problem: When I use Debug.Write(text) it displays the output correctly when I step through the code, however when I run it without debugging, the file only has one character per line.

Question: How do I remove the carriage returns and line feeds while running the entire program?

Here is the relevant code:

```
namespace Instrument_GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private StreamWriter StoreData1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void cbo_Instrument_1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            string date = string.Format("{0:d}-{1:d}-{2:d}", time.Year, time.Month, time.Day);
            string path = "C:\\Users\\rafii\\Desktop\\";
            if (cbo_Instrument_1.Text=="GPS")
            {
                string file = path + date + '_' + cbo_Instrument_1.Text + ".txt";
                txt_filename_1.Text = file;
                txt_COM_PORT_1.Text = "COM11";
                txt_BAUDRATE_1.Text = "4800";
            }
            string instrument = cbo_Instrument_1.Text;
            string file1 = path + date + '_' + instrument + ".txt";
            StoreData1 = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        string InputData = String.Empty;

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputData = serialPort1.ReadExisting().Trim();
            if (InputData != String.Empty)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });    
            }
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (chk_DISPLAY_1.Checked == true)
            {
                TextBox1.Text += text;
            }
            if (chk_SAVE_FILE.Checked == true)
            {
                Debug.Write(text);
                StoreData1.WriteLine(text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));

                StoreData1.Flush();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is the issue that in the output window you're seeing them with the carriage return? Or in your actual data stream? Because though your Debug.Write statement shouldn't insert a carriage return, StoreData1.WriteLine will. You should be using StoreData1.Write...

Comment: @Griffin I am seeing the issue in the output window.  I got rid of the carriage returns and line feeds in the data stream.

Comment: You have removed all "\r" and "\n" from within text, but when you call StoreData1.WriteLine it is writing text + "\r\n" to the stream. In order to prevent the addition of "\r\n" to the end of the write call StoreData1.Write instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, the `TextWriter.WriteLine()` method is designed *specifically* to add newline characters to whatever you pass it. Assuming the serial I/O is slow enough that your data-received handler is called for each individual character that is received, then yes, you will find the output file has a newline between each character.

You could observe slightly different results, with newlines between larger chunks of text, depending on how exactly the serial data is buffered before your data-received handler is called.

So instead of calling `WriteLine()`, you should call `Write()`.

Note also that if you are going to remove individual `\r` and `\n` characters, there is no point in looking for pairs of those characters as well. Just remove the `\r` and `\n` characters, and that will take care of the pairs. (As an aside, I'll also note that using the `string.Replace()` method can be expensive, especially in looping contexts or when you call it multiple times on the same object).

I.e. your code should look more like this:

```
StoreData1.Write(text.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));
```

Now, note that the above removes *all* newline characters from the data. That will produce a single run-on line of text in your output file. If that's what you intend, great. But if the only reason you put the calls to `Replace()` in there was because you were trying to remove the *extra* line breaks you were getting, then maybe all you really want is `StoreData1.Write(text);`.